# In Apache Camel how to check if the in coming message contains a string

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel to pass messages. The program is in Java. I want to check if the incoming message contain text("Fault Code: 0") and ("Warning Code: 0")  and if it does then do not send it forward....I have a route as below

```
    from("direct:operation-send-"+getId())
.id("direct:operation-send-"+getId())
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
.doTry()
      .choice()
           .when( ! body().contains("Fault Code: 0") )               
       .to(httpUrl.getUri())
       .endChoice()
     .endDoTry()
     .doCatch(Exception.class)
         .to("log:HTTP_SEND_CONNECTION_ERROR?level=ERROR&showHeaders=true")
         .to("direct:operation-store-"+getId())
```

But this part when( ! body().contains("Fault Code: 0") )  is giving me a compilation error. I want to know how to  check for a condition(of the text in the message) in a Camel route...........Would appreciate any help!!

Comment: What error does this piece of code produce? Could you give us a stack trace at least?

Comment: The only error `body().contains(...)` can produce is `NPE` if body is `null`. Or maybe `body()` can itself throw something, but what could it possibly throw?

Comment: It is a compilation error......I want to know how to  check for a condition(of the text in the message) in a Camel route...when I add the ! , I see a compilation error

Comment: You still did not provide the error log. What does the compiler say?

Comment: Try `body(String.class)` instead of `body()`

Comment: The error says----The operator ! is undefined for the argument type(s) Predicate

Comment: The method body(Class<String>) from the type BuilderSupport is deprecated

Comment: Try `body(String.class).not().contains("Fault Code: 0")` (without the negation - `!`). Here's the documentation for [ValueBuilder](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/ValueBuilder.html) (it is something that `body()` returns).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140006/discussion-between-jezor-and-aparna).

Comment: yes that worked thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static method [body()](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.18.3/org/apache/camel/builder/BuilderSupport.html#body--) from [BuilderSupport](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.18.3/org/apache/camel/builder/BuilderSupport.html) class produces a [ValueBuilder](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.18.3/org/apache/camel/builder/ValueBuilder.html) object. This object provides a fluent way to build a `Predicate`, which is one of the idioms in the world of functional Java.

I'm not going to get into details of how `Predicate`s work (you can read about them more [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/how-to-use-predicate-in-java-8/)), but they cannot be used as a simple `boolean`. This means, a predicate cannot be negated with negation sign - `!`, and that is what you're trying to do here.

So instead of:

```
.when( ! body().contains("Fault Code: 0") )
```

you need to use `ValueBuilder`'s methods to form your conditions.

Also, notice that you are trying to check if your body contains a `String` object. I am not sure if you need to tell `ValueBuilder` about it, [but it seems like a common practice in Camel](http://camel.apache.org/validate.html) (which I have never used myself).

Knowing those two things, the solution seems simple. Just replace the offending line with:

```
.when(bodyAs(String.class).not().contains("Fault Code: 0"))
```

Camel is a huge library that heavily operates on Java 8 features. Make sure you know how to use them properly first (there are many tutorials, [this one](https://dzone.com/articles/functional-programming-java-8) for example).

---

**EDIT**: the [body(Class)](https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/BuilderSupport.html#body(java.lang.Class)) method is deprecated in newer versions of Camel (in 2.18.3 at least), so you should use [bodyAs(Class)](http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.18.3/org/apache/camel/builder/BuilderSupport.html#bodyAs-java.lang.Class-) instead.

Always check javadocs when you see a warning, because they should contain information on what to replace deprecates with.

**Suppressing a warning it is usually not a good idea!**

The deprecated method will be deleted in future releases, and when that happens, it'll break your build.

Comment: Thankyou this works..but the only thing is body(String.class) is showing as deprecated, but without it, it didn't work..so had to suppress warnings

Comment: @Aparna I fixed it, see edit notes for more information

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Do you know why this: every time that I use `body().toString();` or `body().convertToString();` my `body` request is turned to `InputStreamCache`?

Comment: how to check contains irrespective of the case as well. Means it should work if it is upper or lower case